# iOS app shifted right and can't view full table

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, storyboard

I'm having trouble setting a layout for my iOS app. The entire app is shifted right for some reason as you can see by the label and buttons which are in the middle of the scroll view.

I also can't seem to display the entire table. In the screen shot below "another Item" is supposed to have a checkmark and it is only visible if I shift the table in Main.storyboard far to the left where the actual label for the cell item is half visible.

I have a scroll view inside of the view controller and then a label and three buttons as well as a table view with table view cells.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout with that storyboard? Looks like you might not have set your constraints up properly. You might also want to take a look at Xcode's new [View Debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html) functionality.

Comment: thanks Lukas Spieß, that worked out

Comment: Could you answer your question, so it doesn't show up as open anymore, if it's solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lucas for the answer

> Are you using Auto Layout with that storyboard? Looks like you might not have set your constraints up properly. You might also want to take a look at Xcode's new [View Debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html) functionality.